# How To Count Exact Matches on String by Two or More Letters

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have this simple string:

```
string code = "HelloWorld";
```

Now I want to count the exact matches of:

```
string match = "ll"
```

Which is my expected result is:

```
1
```

Since there is only one exact match of double ll in "HelloWorld"

I am trying to do it by split:

```
var splitted = code.Split(new string[]{ "l", "l" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

But as you would expect, if there was a match of single "l", it will also split it, so I cannot guarantee a good count.

I am trying to do it on a binary number:

```
1011010110110
```

**Which I want to get how many "10"s it have. Here on my example it has 5 exact 10s.**

Comment: Why not do a split using two l characters "ll"

Comment: Also, do you really need LINQ for this? Using string methods would be enough

Comment: What do you expect to be the output of `lll`? 2 or 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use regex. You match the string with the regex and count how many matches there are.

```
Regex.Matches("Hello", "ll").Count
```

That will evaluate to 1.

Remember to `using System.Text.RegularExpressions`!

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you do not need LINQ for this - this can be achieved by using string methods like [Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/tabh47cf(v=vs.110).aspx) and IndexOf, or by using a regex match.

The following code is the simplest, but suboptimal since it creates an extra array:

```
"HelloWorld".Split(new[] { "ll" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Length-1;
```

Also, as @Sweeper pointed out you can use Regex.
If you want to avoid using Regex you can do a small code snippet like this: *(Note: skipped args check for brevity, but you should add them)*

```
public int CountMatches(string searchString, string lookFor)
{
    int count = 0;
    int index = -lookFor.Length;
    do
    {
        index = searchString.IndexOf(lookFor, index + lookFor.Length);
        count++;
    }
    while (index >= 0);

    return count - 1;
}
```

Comment: I tested it using this: var test = "1011010110110".Split(new[] { "10" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length - 1; but it returns 2 instead of 5.

Comment: I think, it will work when you remove `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option and `-1`.

Comment: @JirkaPicek, that's right - I did not expect such behavior from `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Comment: @WillyDavidJr, you're right - thanks for pointing out, I've fixed the code, so now you have two approaches